# Spark Streaming MQTT - Apply schema on dataset

Tags: json, apache-spark, streaming, mqtt

I'm working on DataBricks (Spark 2.0.1-db1 (Scala 2.11)) and I am trying to use Spark Streaming functions. I am using the libraries :
- spark-sql-streaming-mqtt_2.11-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (see here : http://bahir.apache.org/docs/spark/current/spark-sql-streaming-mqtt/)

The following command gives me a dataset :

```
val lines = spark.readStream  
      .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")  
      .option("clientId", "sparkTest")  
      .option("brokerUrl", "tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx")  
      .option("topic", "/Name/data")  
      .option("localStorage", "dbfs:/models/mqttPersist")  
      .option("cleanSession", "true")  
      .load().as[(String, Timestamp)]
```

with this printSchema :

```
root  
 |-- value : string (nullable : true)  
 |-- timestamp : timestamp (nullable : true)
```

And I would like to apply a schema on the "value" column of my dataset. you can see my json schema as folowing.

```
root  
 |-- id : string (nullable = true)  
 |-- DateTime : timestamp (nullable = true)  
 |-- label : double (nullable = true)
```

Is it possible to parse directly my json in the stream to obtain something like that :

```
root   
 |-- value : struct (nullable : true)  
   |-- id : string (nullable = true)  
   |-- DateTime : timestamp (nullable = true)  
   |-- label : double (nullable = true)  
 |-- timestamp : timestamp (nullable : true)
```

For now, I don't see any way to parse the json from a mqtt and any help would be very great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same exact problem today! I used json4s and Jackson to parse the json.

How I am getting the streaming DataSet (pretty much the same as what you have):

```
 val lines = spark.readStream
   .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
   .option("topic", topic)
   .option("brokerUrl",brokerUrl)
   .load().as[(String,Timestamp)]
```

I defined the schema using a case class:

```
  case class  DeviceData(devicename: String, time: Long, metric: String, value: Long, unit: String)
```

Parsing out the JSON column using org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse:

```
val ds = lines.map {
  row =>
    implicit val format = DefaultFormats
    parse(row._1).extract[DeviceData]
}
```

Outputting the results:

```
val query = ds.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .option("truncate", false)
  .start()
```

The results:

```
+----------+-------------+-----------+-----+----+
|devicename|time         |metric     |value|unit|
+----------+-------------+-----------+-----+----+
|dht11_4   |1486656575772|temperature|9    |C   |
|dht11_4   |1486656575772|humidity   |36   |%   |
+----------+-------------+-----------+-----+----+
```

I am kind of disappointed I cannot come up with a solution that uses Sparks native json parsing. Instead we must rely on Jackson. You can use spark native json parsing if you are reading a file as a stream. As so:

```
val lines = spark.readStream
  .....
  .json("./path/to/file").as[(String,Timestamp)]
```

But for MQTT we cannot do this.